# Getting Messages back from postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am initiating a vacuum process in postgres from a C# executable. I want the message to be returned back to my executable, but i I'm not able to get the message back from output window.

In short, I'm looking for equivalent of this in postgres using NPGSQL like:

```
// Display messages this code is for SQL server to reteive data back from message tab

conn.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) {
  stdmForm.txtLastSQLMessages.Text +`=` "\n" + e.Message;
};
```

I want to get this message in my C# code using NPGSQL.

Comment: Get what message? Are you trying to get `VACUUM VERBOSE` output?

Comment: Some quick searching didn't find a way to get `NOTICE` and lower level log messages in the nPgSQL client. You can set `client_min_messages`, but I don't know how to then access the logs from nPgSQL. Take a look at the source code?

Comment: Do u mean the NPGSQl Code?

Comment: Yes i m trying to get Vacuum verbose output

Comment: OK, that's output to the client as log messages, so you need to find a way to get client log messages from within nPgSQL. I didn't see anything obvious in the docs, so consider looking at the nPgSQL source code.

Comment: Come to think of it, you should also ask on the [nPgSQL Forum](http://pgfoundry.org/forum/?group_id=1000140), which looks moderately active. Include a link to this post (see the "share" button?) when you do so, and if possible edit your post here to link to the nPgSQL forum post so others can find your question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the code below. It will give you the complete execution log. From this I just parsed my required log. It's not the best way but I was not able to find anything else.

```
//log the Vacuum command information
NpgsqlEventLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
NpgsqlEventLog.LogName = VacuumLogFilePath + "rolling.log"; 
NpgsqlEventLog.EchoMessages = false;

try
{
    //Run the Vacuum Command
    NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand("VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE", connection); 
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the NpgsqlConnection.Notification event, which is PostgreSQL's counterpart to SqlConnection.InfoMessage. See here: [archive of http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Notification.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307043427/http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org:80/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Notification.html).